# Multiple executable files in one setup using vb.net 2005 windows application

Tags: vb.net

Kindly help me in creating one setup for multiple .exe files....

1)I have 36 .exe file & which needs to be executed in one setup, the project created in VS 2005 using vb.net & is a windows application

2) We need to restore a database during installation process.

3) We also need to set ODBC connection settings during the installation process

Thanks

Comment: Hello, welcome on stackoverflow. Please take some time to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) here, and have a halt at the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. - Always try to include what you've tried before in your question. We are willing to help you when you're stuck, not to do your work for you. :)

Comment: Try [InstallShield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/InstallShield) !